# Flask SQLAlchemy: How to find the primary key value before adding a new object to the session?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

I'm using `b64encode` to create a unique reference string from the primary key in each row in the table. This is my model in Flask SQLAlchemy:

```
class Groups(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    ref_id = db.Column(db.String(20), index = True)

    def __init__(self):
        self.ref_id = id_encode(self.id)
```

However, the `self.id` passed into the `id_encode()` function has a "None" value instead of the primary key's value. From what I can see, it's only possible to get the new primary key value after committing the session, or by [using the flush() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750755/get-primary-key-from-sqlalchemy-before-commit-the-object).

Here's the definition for `id_encode()`:

```
def id_encode(num):
        bts = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(num), 'utf-8'))
        print(num)
        return bts.decode()
```

If there any way to get this to work, or what's a better (but simple) way to do unique reference ID generation? I just don't want the average user to be able to navigate to other groups by entering a numeric ID.

Comment: "what's a ... (but simple) way to do unique reference ID generation?" Have you considered UUID v4?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thank you! I was going to say UUID generates IDs that are way too long, but I found shortuuid after looking up uuid.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is replace the « __init __ » with a class function.

so instead of :

```
class Groups(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
ref_id = db.Column(db.String(20), index = True)

def __init__(self):
    self.ref_id = id_encode(self.id)
```

You should try :

```
class Groups(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
ref_id = db.Column(db.String(20), index = True)

def generate_id(self):
    self.ref_id = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(self.id), 'utf-8'))
```

Then when you create a new group object, just remember to use the function before committing.

```
group = Groups(id=xxx, arg2=xxx, arg3=xxx etc) 
# omit "id" if you set it to autoincrement
group.generate_id()
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: " just remember to..." tends to be a bug magnet, because most humans forget things easily.  You could avoid this risk here by modifying `generate_id()` so that it would work as a [column default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html) or setting the value via an [attribute event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#attribute-events).  That said, in this particular case Ilja's UUID suggestion is probably the best approach.

Comment: "Then when you create a new group object, just remember to use the function before committing" does not differ from using `__init__`, if a flush has not taken place in between adding the object to session and calling the generator function.